# How to compare numbers in a complex linux text file?

Tags: linux, bash, file

I have a huge file that looks like this:

> 1234    4567    3566
>
> 2432    434     95054
>
> 382     9983    90

with tabs separating the numbers.

I'm new to linux and to BASH and I need to use the terminal (not a script in a other file) to compare all the numbers in the 3rd column.

I tried the grep command but I can't find a way to do everything I want (find the file, open it, go to the 3rd column, find the biggest number). Is it possible to do with only one command? With pipes maybe?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried out the suggestions you have been provided? Do you require any additional clarification?

Comment: Yes I tried out the suggestions and it works! I understand how to use awk now thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to print the line in your file which has the highest value in the third column. This awk script does that:

```
awk '$3>max{max=$3;line=$0}END{print line}' file
```

`$3` refers to the third column. If it is greater than the current value of `max`, update `max` and set `line` to the contents of the whole line, `$0`. Once the file has been processed, print out the line with the maximum value.

If you only want to find the maximum number and aren't concerned about the rest of the line, the script is slightly simpler:

```
awk '$3>max{max=$3}END{print max}' file
```

This simply updates the value of `max` whenever the value of the third column is higher and prints it once the file has been processed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$ awk '$3>v{v=$3}END{print v}' file
95054
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry my answer took so long I had a rough week. I understand what you wrote and it's very useful. Now, if I want to print the 20 biggest numbers, how would I do that? I tried making more variables but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks again for your help!